# Performing two different operations in single job

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to perform two database operations using Room in one job and only first operation is executing.

Inside my ViewModel I have following:

```
val supervisorJob = SupervisorJob()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + supervisorJob)
```

And I have two database operations which returns me `Flow`, as follows:

First Operation:

```
 firstRepo.getSomeData1().collect {
            val size = it.size
            Log.d(TAG, "Size of list is $size")
            it.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "Data1 name: ${it.name}")
            }
        }
```

Second Operation:

```
secondRepo.getSomeData2().collect {
            val size = it.size
            Log.d(TAG, "Size of list is $size")
            it.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "Data2 name: ${it.name}")
            }
        }
```

And I am trying to perform this in following manner and it only executes and prints `firstRepo.getSomeData1` and ignores `secondRepo.getSomeData2`

My method:

```
fun getAllProtocols() = scope.launch {

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        firstRepo.getSomeData1().collect {
            val size = it.size
            Log.d(TAG, "Size of list is $size")
            it.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "Data1 name: ${it.name}")
            }

        }

        secondRepo.getSomeData2().collect {
            it.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "Data2 name: ${it.name}")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If I wrap each operation in `launch{}` then they both gets executed.

**I am not able to understand why this is happening? And why can't they both execute in same Job
Or Is it enforced that one job can execute only one asynchronous or db operation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the same coroutine is executed sequentially.
Flows are sequential, too - `collect` function is just a regular suspending function that returns only when the whole flow is collected (or when an error is thrown).

In other words, looking at your code, it means that collection of the second flow *cannot start until the first flow is fully collected*.

And there is the problem, the first flow is never fully collected, because it just keeps observing Room database for changes indefinitely.

You already know how to fix the problem - launch collection operations in separate coroutines to make them concurrent:

```
fun getAllProtocols() = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

    launch {
        firstRepo.getSomeData1().collect {
            val size = it.size
            Log.d(TAG, "Size of list is $size")
            it.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "Data1 name: ${it.name}")
            }
        }
    }

    launch {
        secondRepo.getSomeData2().collect {
            it.forEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "Data2 name: ${it.name}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Dispatchers.IO` is not needed here. Aren't these DB operations suspendable and non-blocking?

Comment: You're right, it's not needed for DB operations (Room has its own IO dispatcher that it will switch to). I just kept it because OP is using it in his original code - if those lists are expected to be short and updates infrequent, then there is no point in switching to IO dispatcher just to log some data. But again, that's just an assumption, we don't know how 'heavy' is OP's use case.

Comment: It is _much_ more likely they are using it inappropriately. This is the most common mistake I see in many questions here. The Room APIs seem to have recently been blocking, then switched to suspending, but the examples in the docs weren't updated.

Comment: There is another important thing to note here - IO dispatcher is backed by multiple threads, so there is possibility of race conditions - OP, your log entries could become interleaved. If that's a problem, then you should use the main dispatcher or any other dispatcher backed by a single thread (or use mutex if you still want to keep using IO dispatcher).

Comment: question to both of you @Guest21 and @Marko Topolnik. what do you mean by `Dispatchers.IO` is not needed here? Aren't we suppose to use that when doing DB operations(Room)? Feel free to correct me.

Comment: @Guest21 can you provide some reference to this _"Room has its own IO dispatcher that it will switch to"_. I am trying to find reference to this but I can not find anything. I can see here they are querying for dispatcher. Link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/room/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/room/CoroutinesRoom.kt

Comment: Check android developers blog - there was a post about that some time ago. Or, check this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-kotlin-coroutines/#9) - "Queries with a `Flow` return type always run on the Room executors, so they are always main-safe. You don't need to do anything in your code to make them run off the main thread."

Comment: @guest21 `IO dispatcher is backed by multiple threads, so there is possibility of race conditions` -- this isn't true, a coroutine always executes sequentially no matter how many threads the dispatcher uses. "Sequentially" doesn't imply "on a single thread", just "on one thread at a time".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The part of my comment that you're quoting has nothing to do with how the code is executed inside the same coroutine. OP is running not one, but two coroutines, and both of them log _multiple entries_ for each item collected. The entries generated for one item could become interleaved with the entries generated for another item if those two items are collected from different coroutines - and that's because those two coroutines are run on a multi-threaded dispatcher.

Comment: I see, although using the dispatcher as a tool to control coroutine interleaving isn't the best approach, it's more of a hack. If at any time you add a suspendable function to the `collect` block, it will introduce another point where interleaving can happen. Ordering should be controlled explicitly, for example with `flattenMerge`.

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't work beacuse the code in a coroutine is executed sequentialy. `withContext` is a blocking function that waits the code to finish that is when the first flow finish. You can use something like this:

```
scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    supervisorScope {
        launch {
             firstRepo.getSomeData1().collect {
                  val size = it.size
                  Log.d(TAG, "Size of list is $size")
                  it.forEach {
                      Log.d(TAG, "Data1 name: ${it.name}")
                  }
             }
       }

       launch {
           secondRepo.getSomeData2().collect {
               it.forEach {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Data2 name: ${it.name}")
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

The `supervisorScope` function is a blocking function that waits the child coroutines to finish.

Comment: The code of @Guest21 should not work because the two coroutine are launched in the scope of first coroutine and when the first coroutine finish the child coroutines will die.

Comment: You're wrong, the code works. The first coroutine cannot just 'finish' - it has to wait for both of its child coroutines to finish first.